# gridExtra tableGrob erroneous output

Tags: r, gridextra

Couldn't solve gridExtra tableGrob's erroneous output. All packages and R are up to date. Using this code in .rmd file.

Example from vignette

```
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
d <- head(iris[,1:3])
grid.table(d)
```

This does not give any output.

```
tableGrob(d)
```

This gives crappy output with the following message: *TableGrob (7 x 4) "rowhead-fg": 56 grobs*

[image]

Comment: Are you knitting to HTML? Are you running exactly that code? I can knit your code in an .Rmd file and the output of `grid.table` is rendered fine.

Comment: Running exactly the same code after R restrat. I'm just trying to see the output between code chunks in rstudio. Later, I would like to use the table in a patchwork-combined plot.